# watch app and ios app communication is not clear

Tags: ios, watchkit

I read that communication between watch app and its companion iOS could be made using WCSESSION and WCSESSIONDELEGATEPROTOCOL.

However there is nothing said about how the entire communication happens. That is, which transport protocol is used etc... Is there a standard port used since no port number is specified? I am looking for something similar to OSI Model. I found these sources so far

https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/

and 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSessionDelegate_protocol/

Comment: please if you think that the question is not useful, I will be glad to know why?

Comment: It'd help to put some effort into the way you're presenting your question. For example, use proper punctuation and capitalization, and don't (double!)quote your own question. Remove the part where you apologize for your inexperience (it just wastes readers'  time and doesn't add anything) and just ask the question. Also, it's hard to understand what you're asking -- if you have a mechanism that communicates between the devices, how does the transport mechanism affect what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Caleb thanks for your suggestion.. no it does not affect it.. I am just trying to understand how the entire communication works

Comment: You don't need to know these details for a basic communication app, what kind of a problem is your question supposed to solve ?

Comment: @A-Live I have not yet encountered a problem requiring those details. However I believe that understanding the communication may help in a long run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained at [*About Bluetooth and Wi-Fi on Apple Watch*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204562), the watch will use both Bluetooth and Wi-fi to connect to the phone, switching between them as necessary. Bluetooth is preferred since it requires less power.

The specifics of low-level communication between the devices appears not to be documented. That may be because Apple may change how that communication works in the future, or because they just haven't gotten around to documenting it yet, or to maintain security, or because they want developers to use the provided WCSession mechanism rather than trying to roll their own. For all practical purposes, though, you can assume that the communication happens by magic -- the details don't matter as long as it works.

Note that as developers, we do this *all the time.* Every public class in Cocoa Touch hides implementation details that we don't need to concern ourselves with, and the same is true of every other framework that you use but don't have the source code to.

There's certainly nothing wrong with wanting to know how devices use different communication technologies *in general,* and there are lots of books about that sort of thing. That said, as a developer trying to write a watch app, the only reason to worry about details of how the watch and phone communicate is if you're trying to intervene in or subvert that communication, or if you find that it doesn't work correctly and are trying to understand why.

Comment: thanks a lot... I can now go on with the development in peace